# How to test a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, servlets, htmlunit, http-unit, jwebunit

I have built a "Dynamic Web Project" in Eclipse using JSP's and servlet.

I want to test this project using a framework. I am new to test driven development.

After a few searching on how to test servelets and Jsp's with navigations I found out that either of the following frameworks can be used to test a servlet

1) HttpUnit
2) HtmlUnit
3) JWebUnit

Which is a good and easy-to-use framework?

My main concern is to test the navigations inside a Jsp. I couldn't fine any proper guide or piece of code for testing Servlets and Jsp's along with the navigations.

Can anyone please brief me with one jsp and one servlet test code along with the navigations? or refer me a link where I can find this functionality